# Symlinks in a path pointing to another drive block `ls`

Tags: ls, symlink

I recently took out some specific directories from my `/home` directory and put them on an external hard drive that is mounted on another path (`/mnt`).

Inside my home directory I have created symlinks to some of the old directories in order to access them seamlessly (for instance, I moved my `~/media/music` to `/mnt/media/music`).

Now, if I `cd` into a directory that contains one of these symlinks (for instance, I created a symlink for `/mnt/media/music` into `~/media/`) and then I issue an `ls` command, the external hard drive starts spinning and the output of `ls` is blocked until some data (don't know what) is read from the disk (I suppose, since the spinning).

I was wondering the reason for which it happens. It doesn't seem to be necessary to load anything from the external hard drive just to show the symlink (`cd`ing into the symlink and then `ls` is another thing, though it's not what I'm referring to here). So why does this happen?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `ls -f` probably wouldn't.

Comment: Is your `ls` an alias (or function)? If yes, to what?

Comment: @fra-san my ls, in fact, an alias to `ls -vC --color=auto --group-directories-first`. Is the sorting the problem? Anyway, I'll try `ls -f` as soon as my drive stops spinning.

Comment: @A.B Yes, `ls -f` does not block... So it can be the sorting or the colorization...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--group-directories-first` asks `ls` to resolve whether a symlink points to a directory or file.

For that, it needs to access the target file system, i.e. your external hard drive.

So, that's why `ls` takes a long time when you use it.

@Kusalananda raised the very valid question whether coloring wouldn't require the same access: it doesn't; coloring (as far as my `ls` 8.32 is concerned, with my current very default dircolors) doesn't check the type of target. Way I checked this was by running

```bsh
cd /tmp
mkdir dir
cd dir
touch testthing
ln -s /doesnotexist deadlink
strace -o /tmp/withlink ls --color
rm deadlink
strace -o /tmp/withoutlink ls --color
```

and then `diff /tmp/withlink /tmp/withoutlink`. Things are, aside from randomized memory addresses, identical up to `getdents64`, which returns a list of dirent'ries which already contain the "is this a symlink?" information. The existence of the target (or its type) is never checked.

Comment: Doesn't also the coloring require that the target of the symbolic link is accessed? (to see whether it exists and what type it is)

Comment: @Kusalananda nope, doesn't, see my edit :)

Comment: I understand now...  Thank you very much.